# Read XML file or create new one with root element if file doesn't exist

Tags: qt, qfile

I need to create a `QDomElement` with the root element of my XML file in the constructor of my program.

For this the program first tries to read the file. If the file can't be read a new file will be created with the root element. After this I get the root element of my file.

Following is my code for this:

```
bool hadToCreateXML=false;
bool wasLoadedCorrectly=false;
fileXML.setFileName("C:/logs.xml");
if(!fileXML.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
    cout << "fail open, file does not exsist?" << endl;
    if(!fileXML.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        cout << "failed creating file" << endl;
    }
    else{
        ui->outputText->append("First time running");
        hadToCreateXML=true;
        QDomDocument tempFirstTime;
        tempFirstTime.setContent(&fileXML);
        tempFirstTime.createElement("MyRoot");
        QTextStream stream(&fileXML);
        stream << tempFirstTime.toString();
        fileXML.close();
    }
}
else wasLoadedCorrectly=true;

if(hadToCreateXML||wasLoadedCorrectly){
    if(!documentXML.setContent(&fileXML)){
        cout << "failed to load doc" << endl;
    }
    else {
        rootXML=documentXML.firstChildElement();
        fileXML.close();
    }
}
```

It looks messy and unfortunately this doesn't work as intended. If the file doesn't exist it will be created but the root element will not be added to it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
QFile fileXML;
bool hadToCreateXML=false;
bool wasLoadedCorrectly=false;
fileXML.setFileName("G:/logs.txt");
    if(!fileXML.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        qDebug() << "failed creating file" << endl;
    }
    else{
        hadToCreateXML=true;
        QDomDocument tempFirstTime;
        //tempFirstTime.setContent(&fileXML); don't use
        tempFirstTime.appendChild(tempFirstTime.createElement("MyRoot"));
        QTextStream stream(&fileXML);
        stream << tempFirstTime.toString();
        qDebug() << "data "<< tempFirstTime.toString();
        fileXML.close();
    }
```

Your mistakes: you opened file as `WriteOnly` but try to call `setContent`, you try to read file, it is forbidden. You will get next debug error:

> QIODevice::read: WriteOnly device

Also use `QFile::exists()` to check is file exist.

So your code should be something like:

```
if(fileXML.exists())
    //read
else
    //write
```

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfile.html#exists-2